# Can cookies be read by third parties?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

So I want to pass a random number generated by the js script I wrote, the information has to be hidden until passed to my php script, after that it can be displayed publicly, is it possible for someone to see the information the cookie is holding? If it is possible is there a way to pass information from js to php without anyone being able to see it?
Edit- I might've done it wrong but I basically want to make a roulette with hashing and such, I have the hashing done on php and I'd like to animate the roulette using js, animating the roulette using js requires the number that the hashing process makes(I generate a random string and then hash it and use hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) % 15; on it to make a number from it), I'm scared that someone will find out the hash before it reaches js and is animated, because after animation the hash is useless

Comment: if something is wrote in local browser, than can be read from user.

Comment: https cannot be read when intercepted on the way *** 
Anything generated in your browser can be read using inspect on that browser *** Keyloggers and other spystuff can intercept what is typed on the computer

Comment: Hi, do you mean even the user himself? or anyone other than that user?

Answer (score 0):

A very complex question.
There are several ways in which information can be obtained.
First, the browser itself has access to what it holds. We have no way of preventing this information from existing in the browser.

If your site is exposed to xss then you can run scripts on it.
As a result, you will be able to access the information you have saved at the javascript level, cookies and everything around.

There is another attack that could be in the communication between the site and the "man in the middle" server.
HTTPS communication can help you defend against attack.

Are there other ways?
Probably so, it might be easier to help if we understand the exact challenge you are facing

Comment: I might've done it wrong but I basically want to make a roulette with hashing and such, I have the hashing done on php and I'd like to animate the roulette using js, animating the roulette using js requires the number that the hashing process makes(I generate a random string and then hash it and use hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) % 15; on it to make a number from it), I'm scared that someone will find out the hash before it reaches js and is animated, because after animation the hash is useless.

Comment: The idea should be as follows:
When you click on the roulette the roulette will start spinning, at the same time the code will issue an AJAX request to the server, from which it will receive the roulette results.

Comment: As I understand, ajax can't be read by anyone until chosen to be shown, right?

Comment: No.
There is always a fear that the information may be exposed if the site is not written securely - but the information will come after you click on the roulette, and you have saved the roulette results in your database.

Just knowing does not matter
Or I did not understand the meaning of your app

Comment: I'm still not sure what I'm doing too, I have no idea how my hashing works and how I make a number out of it, I'm thinking that if they know how I make the number from the hash they could just use the same code to see the outcome before it's even shown on the screen just by knowing the hash and how I make the number that rolls out from it.